# Magento2.3.1 How to overide Model file?

Tags: overrides, model, magento2.3.1, layer

I am using Magento2.3.1 and i trying to override model in our theme.

our model file path `app/code/XXXX/General/Model/Layer`

```
<?php
namespace XXXXX\General\Model\Layer;

class FilterList extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList
{
    public function getFilters(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer)
    {
        if (!count($this->filters)) {
            $this->filters = [
                $this->objectManager->create($this->filterTypes[self::CATEGORY_FILTER], ['layer' => $layer]),
            ];
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($this->filterableAttributes->getList() as $attribute) {
             echo "test";   
           }    

        }
        return $this->filters;
    }
}
```

`app/code/XXXXX/General/etc` our di.xml file path and below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList" type="\XXXX\General\Model\Layer\FilterList" />    
</config>
```

please check it my code and reply me how to wrong?

Comment: <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList" type="XXXX\General\Model\Layer\FilterList" />    
</config>

Please remove \ from type as above and try again.

Comment: i already remove it \ from type inside but not working on it

Comment: @RvSingh might this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50004762/how-to-override-magento-catalog-model-layer-filterlist-in-magento-2-2-3

Answer (score 2):

same issue not override that file,

I have follow same as per above but not working
need to override this : Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList" type="Mageone\Filterlist1\Rewrite\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList" />
</config>



<?php
namespace Mageone\Filterlist1\Rewrite\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer;
class FilterList extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList
{
   public function getFilters(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer)
    {
        //need to customise here
    }
}
```

can you please anyone help

Answer (score 0):

Using virtual_type

Once Verify the core file of di.xml arguments passing
\vendor\magento\module-catalog\etc

```
<!-- replace this code with your di.xml -->
<!-- For Category Filter -->
 <virtualType name="categoryFilterList" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filterableAttributes" xsi:type="object">XXXX\General\Model\Layer\FilterList</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

<!-- For search filter -->
    <virtualType name="searchFilterList" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filterableAttributes" xsi:type="object">XXXX\General\Model\Layer\FilterList</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

**.../modulename/extensionmodule/Model\Layer**

```
<?php

    namespace XXXX\Genera\Model\Layer;

    /**
     * Override FilterList Class
     */
    class FilterList extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList
    {
        ......Your Code Here......
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: can you please explain properly so i am confusing where is put it code <virtualType name="categoryFilterList" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filterableAttributes" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList</argument> like code

Comment: code updated please have a look

Comment: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/2816

Comment: code is not working it